# Typing issue with AOSP

Tags: text-input

Sometimes, when typing, the AOSP keyboard misbehave very badly.

The characters may not appear, may the cursor move forward without placing a single character(if typed in between text).

When pressing backspace(delete), the cursor move backword without deleting,

When typing in a textarea in browser, nothing is shown and when click on the addressbar, everything we typed is there.

What is the problem and how to solve it??

It happens occasionally, not all times.

I am using YU YUREKA AO5510 ( CYANOGEN 12.1 - NON ROOTED)